# How do I remove outlier data from a Google Analytics chart?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to display a pie chart of pageviews for my site, but there are a few outlier pages I do not want included.

Is there a way to exclude those sites from the pie chart?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Advanced Segments](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033017) to exclude that pages and put together that chart after applying that segment (which excludes those outlier) pages.

Comment: Ravi, please explain how this is done.

Answer (score 0):

It is done as follows (this example is for excluding visits where "time on page" > 20 minutes, but you can change it to suit your needs):

1. Near the top of any report, under report title, click "advanced segments"
2. On the far right, click "+ New Custom Segment"
3. Change "Include" to "Exclude"
4. Click the green drop-down and change the value to "Time on Page"
5. Leave "Greater Than" as-is
6. Enter 1200 (seconds) for 20 miniutes
7. Click "Save Segement"

That new segment is automatically applied to the report and graph.